# selecting data from spreadsheet with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, python-module

I have a excel spreadsheet with 1000s of rows and I need to randomly select data (considering all possible combinations) based on certain criteria.

For example:
spreadsheet that contains movies names and select randomly movies which are

- (50% > year 2000 & 30% between 1980-2000, 20% less than 1980) &
- (50% thriller & 50% action)
- ...also total movie time should be 30 hours so select more than one movies ..

Is there any python module that gives me random generated data with these type of filters? I am looking into Pandas but not sure if it can help?

Comment: why you have only Excel tag if you're looking for a python modul? please clarify what type of answer you're looking for. "50% > year 2000 & 30% between..." that means at least 5 movies for me to be at least close to this ratio, that surely won't fit in 4 hours.... Your question is very confusing, please clarify it.

Comment: Raw data is in excel spreadsheet format which is why I tagged under excel. I am looking for either logic to perform this action or if there is any module which can give me similar output. From timing perspective I think I agree with you and we should have more timing...lets say 30 hours. I will also update my original problem...thanks!